# Measuring the similarity between data sets

Tags: analysis, correlation

Suppose I have a data set of movie ratings:

```
Movie    My Rating    Critic1 rating    Critic2 rating
  a          2             2                 4
  b          4             3                 1
  c          3             4                 5 
  d          2             3                 4
  e          3             3                 5
```

(assume each movie is rated 1-5)

How would I calculate which critic has the most similar taste to my own movie ratings? Preferably, I would like to calculate a percentage of similarity.

Comment: I’m sure there are many ways. For example, you could just use the percentage of ratings that are the same, although I’m sure most would recommend against that. Have you looked at cosine similarity?

Comment: You could use the Euclidean distance between two vectors $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ and $\vec{y}=(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)$ given by the formula $$d(\vec{x},\vec{y})=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2+\cdots+(x_n-y_n)^2}$$